# Python : Cannot retrieve shape of numpy matrix in dict

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am storing numpy matrix in a dict. However, when I try to find out the shape of the matrix, it fails :

```
dict_ = {'one' : np.zeros(shape=(5, 4)), 'two' : np.zeros(shape=(2, 5))}

print type(dict_['one'])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

print dict_['one'].shape()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `shape` is not callable, you need to use it as following :

```
print dict_['one'].shape
```

Comment: Oh dear god, how could I miss this ? Maybe need some rest.
Thanks anyways

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary Welcome, if it was helpful you can say this to community by vote and accepting the answer.

Comment: Can't accept before a certain time elapses. Will do when I am allowed.